# 80's or older sci-fi anime movie dubbed on VHS, MC enters girl's dream realm with robots, similar piloting to fighter g gundam

Tags: story-identification, movie, anime

I remember watching this movie on vhs when I was a little kid (around 06 or 07). What I can remember is that the main character, male long black hair, enters into what seems to be some princess character's dream realm where he needs to locate her and bring her back. The realm is very fantasy like with very acid trip like colors. The MC's mecha that he pilots can parts form and transform into different forms. One being a jet. He fights against the fantasy forces keeping this women in captive. I believe she might have had some sort of mental powers. The piloting method of the mecha was similar to fighter g gundam with wearing suits and using full body to control it. Have been spending time on and off for years to try and figure it out.